# Integration by parts in 4 dimensions

Tags: integration

I'm trying to understand why the following is true (assuming a vanishing boundary term). The integrals are over all space, $\phi=\phi(x)$.

$$\frac{1}{2}\int d^4x \left(\partial_\mu\phi \partial^\mu \phi-m^2\phi^2)\right) = -\frac{1}{2}\int d^4x \left( \phi \partial_\mu \partial^\mu \phi + m^2 \phi^2\right).$$

This is treated by book as trivial but I can't figure out the rule how to manipulate the partial derivatives in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the term $m^2\phi^2$ can be omitted on both sides.

The derivate of $\phi$ is integrated to $\phi$ and the rest of the expression is then differentiated.

This is exactly how integration by parts works.

Comment: I'm wondering what the general formula for it would be.

$$\int d^4x A_\mu \partial^\mu B = ?$$

Comment: Is it $$? = [boundary] - \int d^4x \partial_\mu A \cdot B^\mu$$ ?